# Trazado de lineas en canvas-HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy practicado trazado de lineas en HTML5, y mi navegador (estoy usando Chrome) no esta interpretando la instrucción javaScript con las que hago los trazos sobre el `canvas`. en este caso un circulo con una boca sonriente es lo que espero ver hasta ahora y solo veo el marco del `canvas`

Adjunto la codificación, gracias de antemano

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>canvas-trazado-lineas</title>
      <meta charset="iso-8559-1"/>

      <title>Pagina de programacion en HTML5</title>


      <style>
          #lienzo{
              border: firebrick 2px solid;
          }

          section{
             width: 800px;
             position: relative;
             margin: auto;
          }

           </style>

           <script>
    
               function comenzar() {
        
                   var elemento=document.getElementById("lienzo");
                   lienzo=elemento.getContext("2d");
                   lienzo.arc(400,300,150,0,Math.PI*2,false);
                   line.stroke();
        
                   lienzo.lineWidth=10;
                   lienzo.lineCap="round";
                   lienzo.beginPath();
                   lienzo.arc(400,240,100,0,Math.PI,false);
                   line.stroke();
        
                }

                window.addEventListener("load", comenzar, false);
          </script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <section id="dibujo">
        <canvas id="lienzo" width="800" height="600">


        </canvas>
      </section>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: prueba substituyendo ``window.addEventListener("load", comenzar, false);`` por ``comenzar()``

Comment: Cambia `line.stroke();` por `lienzo.stroke();`

Comment: @RogerTorné Cierto! no lo ví

Comment: solucionado! vaya que error tan tonto (lienzo.stroke()), imagino son los efectos de estar estudiando a las 3am sin café jejeje, muy agradecido amigo!